# Proper link not working in django

Tags: python, django

Okay so I am creating an app which displays a picture with title and description. Here it is

```
{% block content %}

<!-- MODAL IMAGE - This is the preview -->
{% if projects %}

  {% for project in projects %}
  <div class="col-md-4 ">
      <div class="grid mask">
      <figure>
        <img class="img-responsive" src="{{ project.preview.url }}" alt="">
        <figcaption>
          <h5>{{ project.title }}</h5>
          <a data-toggle="modal" href="#modal1" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Take a Look</a>
        </figcaption><!-- /figcaption -->
      </figure><!-- /figure -->
      </div><!-- /grid-mask -->
  </div><!-- /col -->

     <!-- MODAL DETAIL - This is suppos to show the details -->
      <div class="modal fade" id="modal1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
              <h4 class="modal-title">{{ project.title }}</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
              <p><img class="img-responsive" src="{{ project.preview.url }}" alt=""></p>
              <p>Category: {{ project.category }}</p>
              <p>Detail: {{ project.detail }}</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
          </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
        </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
      </div><!-- /.modal -->
  {% endfor %}

{% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

So the app is working, when I add a new project image it shows the preview of all projects created. But when I click on the "Take a look" it does show the pop up window but the image and title always refer to the first image and title. IN SHORT MY MODAL DETAIL ALL REFER TO THE FIRST IMAGE AND TITLE.

Thank you.
eak,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have *only one* element with a given ID (`modal1` in your case). All of your "Take a look" links open the first element with the `modal1` ID, because the rest of the elements' IDs are disregarded. You need to render unique IDs for each project, e.g.:

```
...
<a data-toggle="modal" href="#modal{{ project.pk }}" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Take a Look</a>
...
<div class="modal fade" id="modal{{ project.pk }}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
...
```

Comment: Beat me to it. This probably also means you're going to need to modify your jquery function to target these new modals as well.

Comment: This looks like Bootstrap code, it should be taking the ID of the modal element from the `href` attribute of the `<a>` node, so probably no JS will need to be changed.

Comment: Yup that's bootstrap, I am trying to make it work with django :)

Comment: @lanzz thank you, you're right i did not realize that, i was assuming it would refer to the current project on the list since its on the same for loop. It's working now, much appreciated